# Writing latex in Maple text zone

Tags: latex, maple

In the text zone of Maple, is there a way to write latex?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether you can type in LaTeX and have it be directly parsed as a Maple expression then the answer is no.

There is some facility for importing MathML but even that requires a separate, manual step.